# Future.successful(Failure(Exception)) vs just Future.failed()

Tags: scala, exception, future

I am trying to understand the difference why someone will use `Future.successful(Failure(ServiceException("error")))` rather than `Future.failed(ex)` in Scala.

```
Future.successful(
  Failure(
    ServiceException(ErrorTypes.Validation, "Value should not be more than 30")
  )
)
```

Comment: The same as before, this makes sense if you want an explicit error channel that someone has to recover / deal from.; note this returns a **Fututre** of **Try**. Whereas `Future.failed` creates a failed future with the given exception, so it is hidden until someone calls any of the recover methods.

Comment: `Future.successful(Failure(ServiceException("error")))` seems semantically incorrect. Is this a service that we expect to fail? If so, why are calling it an exception? IMHO it's either an expressivity bug on Scala API (if we can't express a valid use case with clear semantics) or it's a code smell and we should favor clear expression.

Answer (score 4):

It's hard to say why the author did what they did, I can guess a couple of reasons:

1. They are not aware that you can `Future.fail` to return a failed future. This may happen because the signature of future doesn't convey the failure path explicitly in the type. When you see `Future[A]`, you may think this computation must succeed in the future
2. They wanted to be explicit about failure. When I declare `Future[Try[A]]`, I am forcing the caller to deal with the fact that can't directly access `A`, but have to "jump another hop" to get inside for `A`. Although this is delicate, as one can easily write:

   ```
    val f: Future[Try[String]] = ???
    f.map(_.map(str => // stuff with string))
   ```

   But perhaps the signature forces the caller to realize the possibility of failure. Although `Try` is pretty limiting in it's expressiveness as well, as it can only return a `Throwable` on the failure path. I find `Future[Either[E, A]]` to be more expressive in that regards, which allows you to build your own failure hierarchy and encode it in the type.

There is an ever lasting debate regarding unary functor IO types (`Future[A]`) vs bi-functor IO types (`IO[E, A]`, i.e. [ZIO](https://zio.dev/)). I am in favor of bi-functor and have been using it solely recently, and I find it to be really time-saving when I don't have to dig into the implementation to understand the possible failures of a computation.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add on top of the [great answer by @YuvalItzchakov](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65805186/2359227), that writing code as in your question complicates the code and makes it unnatural. For example, let's assume that this future normally an `Int`, something like:

```
val succeeded = true // or any other computation
val future = if(succeeded) {
  Future.successful(42)
} else {
  Future.successful(Failure(new Exception("some failure text")))
}
```

Then first, the type of `future` is `Future[Any]`, because `Any` is the lowest common root of `Int` and `Failure`, which is not convenient. But then, to map on it, you need to do:

```
future.map {
  case i: Int =>
    println(i)
  case Failure(ex) =>
    println(ex.getMessage)
} recover {
  case NonFatal(ex) =>
    println(s"recover ${ex.getMessage}")
}
```

Which feels weird to pattern match `Int` and `Failure` in the same match case. If you do want to pattern match `Success` and `Failure`, we had to do:

```
val succeeded = true // or any other computation
val future = if(succeeded) {
  Future.successful(Success(42))
} else {
  Future.successful(Failure(new Exception("some failure text")))
}
```

But that is already pretty clear as redundancy, right? No one will call `Future.successful(Success(42))`. So I think that it is pretty clear to use `Future.failed(new Exception("some failure text"))`.